# Travel Time from EKEvent

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekeventkit

How can we get Travel Time from iPhone Calendar event.

I mean Travel Time which we will enter at the time of event creation.

I will get All event details using "EKEventStore".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all I got solution. EKEvent not provide property for get travelTime value.

So for get event travelTime we have to get value using "valueForKey"

```
EKEvent *thisEvent  = [events objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Event Travel Time %@",[thisEvent valueForKey:@"travelTime"]);
```

This is returning a value in second so we have to convert it into minute for get actually value.